# Get list of Dataflow pipeline jobs programmatically using Java SDK

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I know there's a `gcloud` command for this:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --help
```

> NAME
>
> gcloud dataflow jobs list - lists all jobs in a particular project, optionally filtered by region
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> By default, 100 jobs in the current project are listed; this can be overridden with the gcloud --project flag, and the --limit flag.
>
> Using the --region flag will only list jobs from the given regional endpoint.

But I'd like to retrieve this list programmatically through Dataflow Java SDK.

The problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a Dataflow pipeline in streaming mode and I want to set the **update** option (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline) accordingly based on if this job has been deployed or not.

e.g. When I'm deploying this job for the first time, the code shouldn't set this `update` flag to `true` since there's no existing job to update (otherwise the driver program will complain and fail to launch); and the code should be able to query the list of running jobs and acknowledge the job's been running and set the `update` option to update it (otherwise `DataflowJobAlreadyExistsException` is thrown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [`org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowClient#listJobs(String)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowClient.html#listJobs-java.lang.String-) that can achieve this.